# How can I add video on background for devise controller registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My view:

```
.background_video[data-no-transition-cache]
  = video_tag @background.footage.url, loop: :loop, autoplay: :autoplay, muted: true, class: 'videos'
.container
  .row
    .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
      h2.text-center Sign up

      = form_for(resource, url: '/users') do |f|
        = devise_error_messages!

        .form-group
          = f.label :email
          br
          = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => 'form-control'

        .form-group
          = f.label :password
          = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off', :class => 'form-control'

        .form-group
          = f.label :password_confirmation
          br
          = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'off', :class => 'form-control'

        .actions
          = f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

I want to add background video to this view. But I don't know where is controller for devise.

How can I find or create controller for Devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite devise controller inside controller folder and named `registrations_controller.rb` and looks like below

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
       #=> for @background video write code here
       super
    end

    # POST /resource
    def create
        super
    end
end
```

And the routes look like

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

If you need devise controller automated then the [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

If you run this command then devise controllers will generate the `/app/controllers/users/` path

Comment: and super must be under my search bachground

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the controller and override or append to its inherited methods. E.g if you want to append to the new method

```
 def new
   @background # use your stuff here
   super # inherit and use devise's method content
 end
```

How to generate a devise controller:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/tool:-generate-and-customize-controllers

Devise's registration controller source code:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can run task

```
rails(rake for older rails version) generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

Where scope is name of controller

More information at [devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) Configuring controllers section